# Laravel: How to query a Model Relationship only if it exists

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a model `Survey` with a column `installer_id` which is related to `hasOne`  another model `Installation` which is related to `hasMany` another model `Assignment`.

I want to write a query to fetch all `Survey` where the `installer_id` is not null, and where IF an `Assignment` exists check all the assignments  if any `status is != 2` ie status = 0 or 1 return the survey.

I tried this query but it does not capture the "if an assignment exists then check the status" part

```
 $surveys = Survey::whereNotNull('installer_id')
            ->orWhereHas('installation',function ($query) {
                return $query->whereHas('assignments',function ($q){
                    return $q->where('status','!=', 2 );
                });
        })->get();
```

I also tried to define a `hasManyThrough` relationship in the model.

```
    public function assignments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Assignment::class,Installation::class);
    }
```

and then using this query

```
 $schedulables = Survey::whereNotNull('installer_id')
            ->orWherehas('assignments',function ($query){
                return $query->where('assignments.status','!=', 2 );
            })->get()
```

Please any suggestions and help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Original answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-query-a-model-relationship-only-if-it-exists?page=1&replyId=735110)

What i needed was the `whereDoesntHave` method.

```
$surveys = Survey::whereNotNull('installer_id')
    ->whereDoesntHave('installation.assignments', fn ($query) => $query->where('status', 2))
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you had the correct approach, however whereNotNull is not necessary if you're already going to check with whereHas, so this way is sufficient I think:

```
$surveys = Survey::whereHas('installation',function ($query) {
                return $query->whereHas('assignments',function ($q){
                    return $q->where('status','!=', 2 );
                });
        })->get();
```

and I think you're missing the `->get();` in your code, thats why you were not getting the results

Comment: I'm still trying to get all the surveys but if they have an installation which is related to the assignment - assignment  status should not be 2.

Comment: Also, I'm checking if `installer_id` is not null which is a column on the surveys table separate from the `installations` relationship